# Pulling a remote docker image through jenkins pipline

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

As seen in this reference http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/jenkins-pipeline/, you can easily pull a docker image within a jenkins pipeline and execute shell commands from within the created container as such:

```
docker.image('ruby:2.3.1').inside {

    stage("Install Bundler") {
      sh "gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri"
    }

    stage("Use Bundler to install dependencies") {
      sh "bundle install"
    }
}
```

this is exactly what i need to do, only i need to pull an image not from the dockerHUb which kinda looks like this : "402837048690.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-repo:latest"

any idea?

Comment: This portion of the URL `402837048690.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` looks like a Docker registry. In that case, it should just work, as long as there's no password required to download the image from the registry. The Docker daemon will recognize that it comes from a registry instead of Docker Hub and it will pull from the appropriate location.

Comment: You'll need to add the registry to the daemon during the pipeline setup. So when the images are pulled they are pulled from the AWS registry and not from docker hub.

Comment: `docker.image('402837048690.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-repo:latest').inside {}` should just work - you may need to configure credentials and other settings if you have a specialized setup, but the `docker pull` command will just work.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! i am fairly new to jenkins and docker, so i might need more clarification on how to configure the credentials (syntax/flow wise). the exception i am getting is this :

  `[workspace] Running shell script
+ docker pull 402837048690.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-repo:latest
Error response from daemon: repository 402837048690.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-repo not found: does not exist or no pull access`

Comment: You should be able to specify your credentials (using the native Jenkins credentials provider) and then pass the credentials ID to `withRegistry()`, as shown here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry